# App Insights to get metrics from embedded PowerBI

Tags: javascript, powerbi, azure-application-insights, powerbi-embedded

I have a web page with PowerBI embedded into it.  I need to collect page loading metrics, however, because PowerBI creates itself an IFrame to use I can't get the timings for the report rendering.

Is it possible to collect metrics from an IFrame?
If not, is there a way to inject JavaScript into the PowerBI report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to use the Power BI Embedded JavaScript events ([link to documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events)). For example you could handle the report loaded event in your page's JavaScript to collect the report loading times. For example:

```
    var reportElement = document.getElementById('pbi-report');

    var report = powerbi.embed(reportElement, reportConfig);

    var reportloadHandler = function (event) {
                // Logging to App Insights here...
        };

    report.on("loaded", reportloadHandler);
```